# List container groups using Azure management APIs fails with System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: c#, azure, azure-container-instances

I'm using some Azure management nuget packages such as the [Azure Container Instances libraries for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/containerinstance?view=azure-dotnet) for months.

A few days ago I noticed some errors when trying to do something simple such as getting a list of container instances - for example:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;

var groups = await _azure.ContainerGroups.ListAsync(loadAllPages: true);
```

Error message is the following:

> The operation was canceled. Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

**This code is being executed on an Azure function but the same error occurs when I'm running it on my machine.**

Stack trace of the exception is the following when running the code on an Azure function:

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
>     at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler+d__15.MoveNext (Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.ProviderRegistrationDelegatingHandler+d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler+d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.UserAgentDelegatingHandler+d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__62.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent.ContainerGroupsOperations+d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent.ContainerGroupsOperationsExtensions+d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.ResourceActions.IndexableRefreshableWrapper2+d__8.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent.ContainerGroupImpl+d__37.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent.ContainerGroupsImpl+d__21.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.PagedCollection2+<>c__DisplayClass21_0+<b__0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.PagedCollection2+d__21.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.PagedCollection2+d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent.ContainerGroupsImpl+d__20.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine+d__01.MoveNext (Polly, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8a3ffc3f8f825cc)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Polly.AsyncPolicy+d__211.MoveNext (Polly, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8a3ffc3f8f825cc)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Commands.CreateBuildAgentInstanceCommand+d__8.MoveNext (Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullPyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: F:\Agent02\w\961\s\src\Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor\Commands\CreateBuildAgentInstanceCommand.csPyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 128)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Commands.CreateBuildAgentInstanceCommand+d__7.MoveNext (Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullPyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: F:\Agent02\w\961\s\src\Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor\Commands\CreateBuildAgentInstanceCommand.csPyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 78)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Function.BuildAgentSchedulerFunction+d__1.MoveNext (Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Function, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullPyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Function, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: F:\Agent02\w\961\s\src\Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Function\BuildAgentSchedulerFunction.csPyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Function, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 89)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Function.BuildAgentSchedulerFunction+d__0.MoveNext (Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Function, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullPyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Function, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: F:\Agent02\w\961\s\src\Pyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Function\BuildAgentSchedulerFunction.csPyra.Automation.BuildAgents.Monitor.Function, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 50)
>   Inner exception System.IO.IOException handled at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler+d__15.MoveNext:
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException (System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult (System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal+<g__InternalFillBufferAsync|38_0>d1.MoveNext (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal+d__341.MoveNext (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+d__61.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>   Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException:

I've tried to update the nuget packages to use the latest version available but the same error occurs, what am I missing here?

Comment: That could be a temporary problem on Azure side. I have got that some days ago and the same time https://azure.status.microsoft/en-us/status was all green.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce the issue anymore but I'll post answer anyway, hopefully it might help someone with similar issues.

**I believe this issue was caused by some messed up container instances**.

Some months ago I had a similar issue - I wasn't able to see the statuses of some container groups in the Azure Portal, there was just a `-` (dash) instead. After deleting these containers everything was working as expected.

Conclusion:

- If listing container instances stop working go to the Azure Portal and check for containers with status `Failed`, `Terminated`, `-` etc. Delete these groups and try to list the containers again

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that there's an internal error the code is throwing and you're not receiving it:

> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task method, that exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out of an async void method will be raised directly on the SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method started.

Take a look if your method is returning a Task:

```
public static async Task UseMethodWithAsyncVoid()
{
    try
    {
        await MethodWithException();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ex Message" + e.Message);
    }
}
```